# css float not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a jquery slider of my own. And I need the list of the slides ul to float left. But its not floating.

html:

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul id="slides">
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x400"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x400"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x400"></li>
    <span class="clear_both"></span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#content .wrapper #slider #slides .slide {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Demo at [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Geum/pen/XmNJXp?editors=110)

I have been trying to figure this out for an hour, but nothing helped me. Could you please help me with this. I will be very grateful to you. Thank you.

Comment: Try giving it a width of 25% and target the `ul`: `#content .wrapper #slider #slides  { float: left; width: 25%; }`

Comment: @MrLister What I want is to have the slider/slide/image the width of the browser, and each slide/image to float left, so that I can animate the margin x to show each image.

Answer (score 0):

It's working, the reason why you think is not working is because the container and the slides widths are 100%. You will get one slide per row. If you want them to be all side by side you will have to make the container overflow's x as hidden and put a child container inside as wide as all slides widths together.

Comment: Also try `whitespace: nowrap;` on the images as there might be a linebreak.

Comment: What I want is to have the slider/slide/image the width of the browser, and each slide/image to float left, so that I can animate the margin x to show each image.

Comment: Like a full screen slider.